# ChartJs resizing when parent div is resized

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I have an angularJs directive that create an ChartJs chart. I would like to resize the chart when the parent div is resized. According to documentation this is possible with:

```
.resize()

Use this to manually resize the canvas element. 
This is run each time the browser is resized, 
but you can call this method manually if you 
change the size of the canvas nodes container element.
```

Here a plunkr: http://run.plnkr.co/KarokZXZ0hGNJpe9/

If you wanna see the files: http://plnkr.co/edit/1cx681?p=info

Try to click button, the chart does not change dimension. If you try to change window size, it's resized.

How can I obtain this without having to change window dimension?

Comment: I can't see either the output or the code when I follow your links to plunkr.

Comment: I have shared the private plunk link, now I have edited my answer with the correct link. Please could you check? thanks

Comment: Still not seeing anything and getting redirected to http://plnkr.co/edit/?p=catalogue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was having this same issue and used the Firebug extension in Firefox to see what ChartJS is doing when you resize the browser. I found that it is passing some parameters to the resize method. The following worked for me:

```
$scope.$apply();
chart.resize(chart.render, true);
```

You may not need the $scope.$apply(), but in my case I found it necessary since I am changing scope properties that cause the canvas size to change.